# Изменить значение пользовательского поля в CRM Битрикс при создании новой сделки?

Tags: php, javascript, битрикс, битрикс24

CRM Битрикс 24 Коробочная версия.

При создании новой сделки добавлены 2 поля типа список - регион и часовой пояс. Стоит задача при выборе из списка региона 1 поля менять значение 2 поля - часовой пояс.

Для задачи думаю повесить обработчик JS на необходимый select с именем пользовательского поля и при его изменении менять значение 2 списка.
Написал заготовку, но не могу найти элемент по

```
document.qyeryselector("select[name=UF_CRM_5822F324B1A4F])
```

Вывожу в консоль полностью значение document - выводиться результат до полной отрисовки страницы.

Свой код пробовал помещать в:

```
bitrix/www/bitrix/js/crm/interface_form.js
bitrix/www/bitrix/components/bitrix/crm.deal.edit/sale.js
```

Как подключить js в компонент, чтобы он срабатывал уже после генерации страницы создания новой сделки?

Comment: BX.ready(function(){ваш код}
пробовали?

Comment: Уже решил проблему через подключение своего скрипта в конце шаблона компонента crm.deal.edit

Answer (score 0):

Уже решил проблему через подключение своего скрипта в конце шаблона компонента crm.deal.edit